# import Y label in barChart at react native chart kit

Tags: react-native, bar-chart, react-native-chart-kit

I want to put in Ylabels these variables [80,90,100] but the graph starts from the min variable i put in the array I found a way to do it in line chart but it does not work on BarChart

```
const data = {      
  labels: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri"],
  datasets: [
    {
     data: [89,85,96,97,94,91,88]
    }
  ]
};

 

  
const graphScreen=()=>{    
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get("window").width;
return(
  
 <View >
    <BarChart
    style={{
    marginVertical: 8,
    borderRadius: 16
  }}
  
  
  

  chartConfig={{
    
    backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
    backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
    backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
    decimalPlaces: 0, // optional, defaults to 2dp
    color: (opacity = 3) => `rgba(200, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
    labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
    style: {
      borderRadius: 30
    },
    data: data.datasets,
    propsForDots: {
      r: "6",
      strokeWidth: "2",
      stroke: "#ffa726"
    }
  }}
  
  segments={3}
  width={screenWidth}
  height={220}
  formatYLabel={() => yLabelIterator.next().value}
  verticalLabelRotation={0}
  
/>

</View>
```

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4B0H.jpg)So in the picture i want in the left side to be these variables!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From looking at the source code for the [BarChart](https://github.com/indiespirit/react-native-chart-kit/blob/master/src/BarChart.tsx#L237) it seems the formatYLabel function should be declared as a property inside `chartConfig` instead of being set as a prop, as is the case with the LineChart.

Another problem you need to be aware of is that this library derives the minimum and maximum y-axis value based on the data array you pass in. The problem with this is that even though you might set your labels to be `[80, 90, 100]`, the values won't necessarily correspond.

Said in another way: If your minimum value label is a different value from the minimum value in your data array the labels won't match up entirely.

Even though taking the minimum value from the data array is the default,
there is a `fromZero` prop you can set to `true` which makes the y-axis start value `0`.

We can take advantage of this by doing something like this:

```
const minValue = 80;

function* yLabel() {
  yield* [minValue, 90, 100];
}

const datapoints = [89, 88, 96, 97, 94, 91, 88].map(
  (datapoint) => datapoint - minValue - 1,
);

const data = {
  labels: ['Sat', 'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri'],
  datasets: [
    {
      data: datapoints,
    },
  ],
};

const App = () => {
  const screenWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
  const yLabelIterator = yLabel();

  return (
    <View>
      <BarChart
        style={{
          marginVertical: 8,
          borderRadius: 16,
        }}
        data={data}
        segments={2}
        width={screenWidth}
        height={220}
        verticalLabelRotation={0}
        fromZero={true}
        chartConfig={{
          backgroundColor: '#e26a00',
          backgroundGradientFrom: '#fb8c00',
          backgroundGradientTo: '#ffa726',
          decimalPlaces: 0, // optional, defaults to 2dp
          color: (opacity = 3) => `rgba(200, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
          labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
          style: {
            borderRadius: 30,
          },
          formatYLabel: () => yLabelIterator.next().value,
          data: data.datasets,
          propsForDots: {
            r: '6',
            strokeWidth: '2',
            stroke: '#ffa726',
          },
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

*I've also changed the amount of segments from `3` to `2`. The segments are the spaces between the labels, so if you want 3 labels you want 2 segments.*

Result:

[image: showcase]

---

So the idea of subtracting `minValue - 1` from each datapoint is to say: What is the difference between my minimum value label `80` and `0` (The start value when `fromZero` is set to `true`). Then subtract another `1` since `0` itself is also part of the range. This gives us a value that signifies how much each value in the data array should be corrected in order to display the bars on the correct height according to the labels we've passed.

*This approach assumes your max value label will be more than the max value in the data array.*

Comment: Yes it actually works thanks a lot. But the values of the bar charts are wrong! For example in Monday has 80 value but in the array is 85

Comment: Ah yes, I just copied your values and labels, but the problem is that the amount of labels isn't equal to the amount of data points so the mapping will be wrong. You are missing 'Saturday' or 'Sat' in the labels array. If this solved your problem by the way you can accept the answer by clicking on the checkmark.

Comment: It still makes the same thing with Monday its 80 in then chart

Comment: You're right. I've realised the problem and updated my answer.

Comment: Actually, if you dont have a max value of 100 in your data, it gonna brake the rules, and you ll get the max value in your data, as the 100% in the yAxisLabels. ;(